# How to implement file watcher to Watch multiple directories

Tags: java

I need to monitor multiple folders for new file notification. I tried for single directory its working fine.
My folder structure looks like
        Path path = Paths.get("c:\users\Test");
        Path path1 = Paths.get("c:\users\test1");
        Path path2 = Paths.get("c:\users\test2");

```
public static void watchOutBoundDirectory(Path path) {
        String newFile = null;
        try {
            Boolean isFolder = (Boolean) Files.getAttribute(path, "basic:isDirectory", NOFOLLOW_LINKS);
            if (!isFolder) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Path: " + path + " is not a folder");
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // Folder does not exists
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        // We obtain the file system of the Path
        FileSystem fs = path.getFileSystem();
        try (WatchService service = fs.newWatchService()) {
            path.register(service, ENTRY_CREATE);
            WatchKey key = null;
            while (true) {
                key = service.take();
                Kind<?> kind = null;
                for (WatchEvent<?> watchEvent : key.pollEvents()) {
                    kind = watchEvent.kind();
                    if (OVERFLOW == kind) {
                        continue; 
                    } else if (ENTRY_CREATE == kind) {
                        Path newPath = ((WatchEvent<Path>) watchEvent).context();
                        Path fullPath = path.resolve(newPath);
                        String newFile = fullPath.toString();
                    }
                }

                if (!key.reset()) {
                    break; // loop
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I tried registering the each directory to watcher.
WatchKey key1 = path1.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE);
WatchKey key2 = path2.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE);
i want to monitor multiple folders for incoming events when program starts. Monitor the folders parallelly till i stop the program. how to implement?

Thanks in advance. Please help
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (true) {
  ....
}
```

Since you have an infinite loop, once you call the watchOutBoundDirectory static function. It will never escape the scope unless you disable the watcher.

Therefore either using multi-thread for each path or passing an array of path to watchOutBoundDirectory and check each path inside the while(true) scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monitor more than one folder, I think that a good solution would be to use a multi-threading program, each thread will monitor a folder.

Comment: What if there were more than 1000 folders? Create a 1000 threads?

Comment: Well then I don't think that using WatchSevice is a good idea.

Comment: Thanks and ill try that. its around 10 folders. andnot more than that.