# how to watch multiple hard disk partitions in FileWacther in java

Tags: java, nio, file-watcher

I am using FileWatcher to watch a whole hard disk partition in my case its D drive  eg: D:/ the code is working fine with one path i provided, all i want is to watch other hard disk partitions as well like C:,D: and E: how can i achieve that here is the code

```
public class FileWatcher {
    private final WatchService watcher;
    private final Map<WatchKey, Path> keys;
    static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GitCloneRepo.class);

    /**
     * Creates a WatchService and registers the given directory
     */
    FileWatcher(Path dir) throws IOException {
        this.watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        this.keys = new HashMap<WatchKey, Path>();

        walkAndRegisterDirectories(dir);
    }

    /**
     * Register the given directory with the WatchService; This function will be called by FileVisitor
     */
    private void registerDirectory(Path dir) throws IOException
    {
        WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);
        keys.put(key, dir);
    }

    /**
     * Register the given directory, and all its sub-directories, with the WatchService.
     */
    private void walkAndRegisterDirectories(final Path start) throws IOException {
        // register directory and sub-directories
        Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                registerDirectory(dir);
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
                if (exc instanceof AccessDeniedException) {
                    return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE;
                }

                return super.visitFileFailed(file, exc);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Process all events for keys queued to the watcher
     */
    void processEvents() {
        for (;;) {

            // wait for key to be signalled
            WatchKey key;
            try {
                key = watcher.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                log.error("InterruptedException ",x);
                return;
            }

            Path dir = keys.get(key);
            if (dir == null) {
                log.warn("WatchKey not recognized!!");
                continue;
            }

            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();

                // Context for directory entry event is the file name of entry
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Path name = ((WatchEvent<Path>)event).context();
                Path child = dir.resolve(name);
                log.info("watching files");
                // print out event
                if (kind == ENTRY_MODIFY) {
                log.info("event.kind().name() {}: child {}", event.kind().name(), child);
                log.info("child {} ends with docx? {} ",child,child.endsWith(".docx"));
                String c= child.toString();
                log.info("**child {}***c.endsWith(.docx)"
                        + ""
                        + " {}",c,c.endsWith(".docx"));
                }
                // if directory is created, and watching recursively, then register it and its sub-directories
                if (kind == ENTRY_CREATE) {
                    try {
                        if (Files.isDirectory(child)) {
                            walkAndRegisterDirectories(child);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException x) {
                        // do something useful
                    }
                }
            }

            // reset key and remove from set if directory no longer accessible
            boolean valid = key.reset();
            if (!valid) {
                keys.remove(key);

                // all directories are inaccessible
                if (keys.isEmpty()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


 //working code
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try{
        Path dir = Paths.get("D:");
        FileWatcher fileWatcher=new FileWatcher(dir);
        fileWatcher.processEvents();
        }

        catch (AccessDeniedException xx) {
            log.error("AccessDeniedException  ",xx);
        }
         catch (FileSystemException x) {
            log.error("exception",x);
        }
        }

}
```

i looked at this question but i did not seemed to solve my problem 
[How to implement file watcher to Watch multiple directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33782037/how-to-implement-file-watcher-to-watch-multiple-directories)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `processEvents` method enters an infinite loop and doesn't return until either the thread is interrupted or the path is gone, which means any code after `processEvents` won't execute until it's done. If you want your `main` method to spin up multiple watchers, you'll need to call `processEvents` from other threads, e.g. with Java 8:

```
// Create watchers
List<FileWatcher> watchers = new ArrayList<>();
try{
    watchers.add(new FileWatcher(Paths.get("D:")));
    watchers.add(new FileWatcher(Paths.get("E:")));
} catch (AccessDeniedException xx) {
    log.error("AccessDeniedException  ",xx);
} catch (FileSystemException x) {
    log.error("exception",x);
}

// Create and start threads
List<Thread> threads = watchers.stream()
        .map(w -> new Thread(w::processEvents))
        .peek(Thread::start)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

With Java 7:

```
// Create watchers
List<FileWatcher> watchers = new ArrayList<>();
try{
    watchers.add(new FileWatcher(Paths.get("D:")));
    watchers.add(new FileWatcher(Paths.get("E:")));
} catch (AccessDeniedException xx) {
    log.error("AccessDeniedException  ",xx);
} catch (FileSystemException x) {
    log.error("exception",x);
}

// Create and start threads
List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
for (FileWatcher watcher : watchers) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            watcher.processEvents();
        }
    });
    thread.start();
    threads.add(thread);
}
```